# ffmpeg produced freezed frames in joining multiple videos

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg produced freezed frames in joining multiple videos
(either using GPU or not same results).

```
 ffmpeg -loglevel 99 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi  -vaapi_device
 /dev/dri/renderD128  -f concat -safe 0 -i "./vids.txt"   -c:v libx265
 -x265-params  crf=18  -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf
 "eq=brightness=0.2:contrast=0.7:saturation=1:gamma=1"    -fps_mode vfr
 -fflags  +genpts  vid_output.mp4
 ffmpeg version 5.1.3-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
 built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened
 --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-
 ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b
 --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d
 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-
 libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
 libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg
 --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-
 librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine
 --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt
 --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame
 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp
 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal
 --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-
 libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-
 libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint
 --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e
 --enable-shared
 libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
 libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
 libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
 libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
 libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
 libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
 libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
 libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
 }}}
```

videos here for 7 days: (vid1 + vid2 = vid_output.mp4)

- [link for videos with vid output](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/16f8b0f60d92369886c11b940f4d404520230706113434/953d45d2eb7bde0e8664630c0ae640a120230706113445/e72977?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid)
- [link for full ffmpeg log](https://file.io/mTUgPSUpi19f)

Comment: I found the problem. Just rotating one of the videos only in metadata, produce these errors. Try to encode two videos - one horizontally and another vertically oriented. Same errors - freeze frames produced by ffmpeg